# Increment in Array on button click with Xamirin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to make a simple app for Android with Xamarin with C#, but I only have experience with C#.
I don't really understand the button clicks I find online, so I don't really understand the mistakes I'm making.
My app is like an restaurant order app. It's only for drinks atm.
I use a button click to increment an particular array index with 1.

```
Button Cola = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.Cola);
Cola.Click += array[0]+1;
```

edit: My idea is, when I click a button, for instance the Cola button, it will increase array[0] with 1. Then I have another button to print it. So when I press cola 5 times, and then press Done it wil print: Cola 5

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try like this

```
//sample
int i=0;
Button click()
{
i++;
array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of different ways, some simpler than others. I have put in 4 different ways to do it on Android. Note that if you call the Set method it will remove all others (as it is Set, not Add method).

```
[Activity (Label = "Increment", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnClickListener
{
    private readonly int[] array = new int[4];

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button cola = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);


        // will happen first (in order of assigned)
        cola.Click += delegate
        {
            array [0]++;
        };

        // second
        cola.Click += (sender, e) => array[1]++;

        // third
        cola.Click += HandleClick;

        // if uncommented this will remove other events
        //cola.SetOnClickListener (this);
    }

    void HandleClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        array [2]++;
    }

    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        array [3]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a anonymous function like this:

```
Cola.TouchUpInside += delegate {
    array[0]++; 
};
```

You can get more information on this site: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/buttons/handle_clicks/

Comment: I don't think you can do that on android

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what you are trying to do, but the recommended way of doing something like this is:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cola);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Do your array increment here like array[1] or something?
         }
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you don't really understand how buttons work in android. 
Have a look at the `setOnClickListener` method of the Button class
You will have to implement a listener that tells the Button how to react when clicked and add the listener to your button

Look at this example:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Good luck!

Comment: If you look at the tags in the post you will notice he is using xamarin in c# to code for Android.